# Logo with glow looks harsh

Tags: logo, png

I have made a logo which needs to be usable by people such as putting into documents and such - Indesign docs and general use.

It is based on a neon light and has glow effects on it.

I would like to keep transparency around the glow so I have saved it as a png. However it looks harsh against the dark backgrounds. I think it might want a screen blend - I'm not sure.

[image: logo trans]

[image: logo linked black indesign]

Comment: One of the first things you should establish on a logo project is what contexts it'll be used in, and you should expect to give guidelines on what colours it can be used against. It's very common to provide multiple versions, e.g. a standard version, and a 'reversed' version for use on dark backgrounds e.g. with blacks swapped for whites, light colours darkened, etc

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I have rolled back to include the image.  It is not fair for the community to take time out to assist you with your issue then you remove or delete the question.  If you dont want an image to be permanently on a question then please do not add it in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Anything with a transparent "glow" or drop-shadow will look different against different backgrounds.

What you need to do is create multiple logos with different coloured backgrounds, and the glow optimised for those conditions.

An alternative to this is to have your logo permanently on its own background (like a car badge for example) and no glow/shadow behind that.

Answer (score 3):

I think the glow needs to be the colour of the type and less white as it's not very realistic of a neon sign.

Like so (sorry about the quick edit):

[image]

As you can see here it doesnt have a white glow, it has a blue glow because the letters are blue.

[image]

What you could also do is turn down the opacity of the glow so it's not a strong on darker backgrounds.

Do this by actually creating a dark layer under your 'neon' and adjust it until you're happy.

If you want the logo to stand out nice on lighter backgrounds then you may just have to create two versions of the logo, one for light backgrounds and one for dark.